# jquery plugin method call inside callback to initialize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-callback

Help me please, how call method inside callback?

Example:

```
var methods = {
     init : function( settings ) { 
     },
     destroy : function( ) {  },
     reposition : function( ) { },
     show : function( ) { },
     hide : function( ) { },
     myfunc : function() {}
  };

//
$.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
        // CALLBACK
        onClickElement : function(element) {}
    };


$('#elementLi').myPlugin({
        onClickElement: function(element) { 
            // here call method myfunc
        }
});
```

How can call myfunc inside onClickElement?

Thank You!
P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention event handlers should set `this` to be the element that's associated with the event.

Your plugin should also arrange to pass the original `event` to whatever function has been configured in `onClickElement`, although you've not included that code here.

Putting that together, you ought to end up with:

```
$('#elementLi').myPlugin({
    onClickElement: function(event) {   // NB: *not* element
        methods.myfunc.call(this, event);
    }
});
```

alternatively, if you've followed the above advice you don't even need the additional `function` block:

```
$('#elementLi').myPlugin({
    onClickElement: methods.myfunc
});
```

So long as your callback uses `.call(element, func)` to invoke `onClickElement` it'll correctly set `this` to be the element and not `methods`.

Comment: Thank You! But, if use `methods.myfunc.call(this, event);` give **methods is not defined**. And in method init, i write 
`init : function( settings ) { 
  
  li = $(this).children("li");

  li.click(function(){

    settings.onClickElement($(this)); // this click element

  });
}`

Comment: @Sergey given the code you posted it shouldn't, unless `methods` is defined in some other scope.

Comment: @Sergey and I would write your function as `li.on('click', settings.onClickElement)` - jQuery will set `this` and pass the `event` automagically.

Comment: So, `li.on('click', settings.onClickElement)` it's work! Thanks) But i don't understand, how call method plugin inside `onClickElement`? Need delegate method? It is don't work `$('ul').myPlugin({ onClickElement: function(event) { this.myfunc(); }}` and `methods.myfunc.call(this, event);` don't work( May be an example or plugin where used this is call?

Comment: please, if You can help, see code and correct me http://jsfiddle.net/SergXP/bSy9S/

Comment: @Sergey ah, you're using _that_ plugin model - I thought your code was somewhat incomplete.  From _outside_ the plugin you would have to write: `$(this).filterSlide('reload')` to call the `reload` method.  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Gxw5z/

Comment: @Sergey also, in this model where you're creating elements inside the plugin, it's convention to actually have the original _container_ element appear as `this` inside the event handler, rather than the sub-elements you've created.

Comment: @Sergey which kinda contradicts what I wrote in the answer text, but is required for consistency.  It ensures that within handlers created by the plugin that `this` reflects the element that you registered the plugin on in the first place.

Comment: Oh, what you need! Thank you very much for your help! Next time I'll know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, sorry)) "me need" :) My bad English) Accept "ok", but i don't can upvote, because my reputation < 15 (